# Composer "Out of memory" bug despite following docs and setting higher limit

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install a new package into my Laravel project. I'm on a Windows 10 machine with plenty of RAM, when installing the package, the terminal exists with:

> Out of memory

I've already increased my memory limit, and running `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` outputs `-1`, I've also tried 2G and 512M

I've tried linking directly to PHP and Composer using the `which` commands and running them that way, I get the same error, and have also tried the `memory_limit` flag on the command, none of which works.

Commands I've tried:

```
1. COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
2. COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
3. /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
4. php -d memory_limit=-1 /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
5. composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Why do I get the "Out of memory" error, surely this is a bug in Composer? Currently using Composer 1.10.10

#### UPDATE 10/05 @ 19:10

Here's an output of `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.laravel/framework : exact version constraints (8.14.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.lcobucci/jwt : exact version constraints (3.3.3) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.nesbot/carbon : exact version constraints (2.41.5) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.spatie/laravel-schedule-monitor : exact version constraints (2.0.2) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.tymon/jwt-auth : exact version constraints (1.0.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.10.21 => 2.0.13)
Composer version: 1.10.21
PHP version: 7.4.1
PHP binary path: C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Comment: Please share more details - for example, which version of PHP are you using? Why not use any more recent version of Composer?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4, and whichever version of Composer is down to personal preference. I have tried both though, and the result appears on both

Comment: Of course, choosing the Composer version might be related to a lot of considerations. But updating to a more recent version might help to check if there is any bug in the version you are using. Please add the output of `composer diagnose` to your question

Comment: Added output @NicoHaase

Comment: Have you tried this in your console/command prompt? `\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.exe -d memory_limit=-1 YOUR_COMPOSER_PATH YOUR_COMPOSER_PACKAGE`

Comment: I have tried that, and I get the `if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then` error with `# We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated`